# C# Непонятно, как происходит сравнение picture box и картинок из resources

Tags: c#

столкнулся со следующей непонятной вещью. Есть таймер, который каждые 250 мс меняет картинки, 0 на 1, 1 на 0.
Тело метода таймера, который не работает:

```
if (isGoRight)
            {
                if (player.Image == Properties.Resources.walkRight0)
                    player.Image = Properties.Resources.walkRight1;
                else
                    player.Image = Properties.Resources.walkRight0;
            }
```

Но если создать массив из этих двух картинок, и сравнивать player.Image с элементами массива, все заработает.

Массив:

```
private readonly Bitmap[] walkRightPictures = new Bitmap[2]
        {
            Properties.Resources.walkRight0,
            Properties.Resources.walkRight1
        };
```

Новое тело метода:

```
if (isGoRight)
            {
                if (player.Image == walkRightPictures[0])
                    player.Image = walkRightPictures[1];
                else
                    player.Image = walkRightPictures[0];
            }
```

В чем магия, объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался, Image - ссылочный тип, и сравнение происходит ссылок, а не самих объектов.